# Side menu (hamburger) button does not close side menu for iOS

Tags: reactjs, navigation, native

1,Tap on Side menu button. the side menu shows up.
2,Tap on Side menu button again. the side menu does not close.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZsw0.png)

How can we get the state that side menu is visible or not? so we can use the following func to show side menu or hide it.

Do we have other better solution for this problem?

`Navigation.mergeOptions('xxxx', { sideMenu: { left: { visible: true } } });`

We tap the Side menu button,the side menu shows up. Then we tap the Side menu button again. hope the side menu close.

Comment: You can able to toggle drawer. It may help - https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-actions/#toggledrawer